# How can I decompress my .zip file and store in ADL/Blob storage?

Tags: azure, zip, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have a ftp as a source connection where some I have zip file and others are not in compress form. I want to copy the files from ftp,decompress zip files and put all files into azure data lake or azure blob storage wherever it's possible to get decompressed.

I'm using copy data activity where I have a source as ftp and properties is zipDeflate,fastest and binary copy and the sink side, I'm just defining the destination ADL path. The files are getting copied to ADL but they're copying in compress form only.
Please let me know if it's possible to achieve the above objective by using copy activity process?

Answer (score 0):

Using binary copy is your issue here, data factory wont understand the data it is moving to uncompress it. Try the same setup without binary copy!

Hope this helped!

Comment: I have unchecked the binary option, and started my copy data activity. I'm seeing the data transfer rate is very low approx 3-4 Kb/s. it took 1 hr to read 13 Mb data. Is it the normal behavior or is it dependent on IR?

Comment: It mostly depends on the hardware where the IR is installed. Check network I/O, cpu, ram usage, etc.

Comment: I tried with different data format(Binary,csv,json) with recursive option unchecked still getting zip files as an output. File inside my zip file is csv.